# Find closest value to a constant in a multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, find, closest

I have a matrix B

```
B(:,:,1) =

         2     8
         0     5

B(:,:,2) =

         1     3
         7     9
```

I want to find the index of a value close e.g. to 2.9.
I tried the following code:

```
[r,c,v] = ind2sub(size(B),find(min(abs(B-2.9))));
```

I get:

```
r =

     1
     2
     1
     2  
 c =

     1
     1
     2
     2  
 v =

     1
     1
     1
     1
```

What I want is:

```
r = 1  
c = 2  
v = 2
```

because I expect 3 to be the nearest value in the entire matrix. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `B` to a column (or row) vector and subtract the constant `k`. `k` may be greater or smaller than targeted value in `B`, so use [`abs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) to remove this problem. Now use [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to find the linear index of the closest value. Then use [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to convert it into corresponding 3D subscripts `r`, `c` and `v`.

```
k = 2.9;
[~, ind] = min(abs(B(:)-k));
[r, c, v]= ind2sub(size(B), ind);
```